# How to wire 2 Female USB plugs into a "Y" USB connector?

Tags: usb

I want to make a USB Y connector from a PC USB backplate it is faster than buying one, fun and educational, (a usb hub is 20 dollars here).

I have many PC USB backplates available to wire into a hub so i had a go:

I  wired all the wires of the same color together in Y formation, but i can only use one of the usb plugs at a time, and not both.

Is there a way to switch round some of the colors so that they are useable concurrently?

I thought USB was simply in series / in parallel.

Comment: green and white are upflow and downflow of data.

Comment: @user4606, no they are not.  They are a (mostly) differential signaling pair.  You might be thinking of asynchronous serial ports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

USB is not simply in series or parallel.

You need a USB Hub chip to build what you are trying to build.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

As @markrages noted, you cannot "Y" a USB connection. It simply won't work.

What you are seeing on pre-built backplates with two USB sockets is that the other end is connecting to **two different** USB ports on the motherboard, combined into a two-wide connector.

To see what I'm saying, please look at figure 6 of [this page](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Installing-Frontal-USB-Ports/90).